# Can ‘manage’ mean ‘achieve with difficulty’?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I often find myself using sentence constructions like:

> Although the train was full, she managed to squeeze on.
>
> I passed the chemistry exam, but never managed history.
>
> Everybody complained about the new computer system, but, after it had been in use for 6 months, they all wondered how we had ever
> managed without it.

Looking in an online thesaurus, I did not find this meaning of ‘manage’.
Is this usage generally-recognised, or just local to where I grew up?

Can you suggest any synonyms to replace ‘manage’ in the above examples?

Comment: Which dictionaries did you check in, Peter? I've found the 'overcome difficulty' subsense in two already. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manage) for example has: << **manage** [verb] [ Intransitive/Transitive ] ...
to succeed in doing something, **especially something difficult**:
• [ + to infinitive ] The pilot managed to land the plane safely.
• [ + to infinitive ] We managed to live on very little money.
• [ I ] Don’t worry about us – we’ll manage. >> [emphasis mine] // in (2), 'managed' is conversational for 'managed to succeed in/with'.

Comment: Look at [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/manage): it has entries for **manage** meaning both "accomplish" and "survive, get by". "cope"/"cope with" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which thesaurus you used, but this meaning is listed in dictionaries. Check entries 3, 4 and 7 from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manage) for example:

> 3. If you manage to do something, ***especially something difficult***, you succeed in doing it.
> 4. If you manage, you succeed in ***coping with a difficult situation***.
> 5. If you say that someone managed a particular response, such as a laugh or a greeting, you mean that it was ***difficult*** for them to do it because they were feeling sad or upset.

Comment: ... So off-topic.